# Action Listener not working in a MVC application

Tags: java, model-view-controller, actionlistener

I have a following problem: I have a small application with a very simple UI. Implemented `Action Listeners` work there just fine. However, the `Action Listener` for the Dialog window and its `Save` button simply refuses to print out the test message.

The code is rather lengthy so i put it on hastebin for convienience.

http://hastebin.com/eqokilawiv.avrasm

I suspect it might have something to do with how the controller is handling adding `OptionsWindow` listeners.

I have tried couple of things to see if they work:

- Having seperate controller for the `OptionsWindow` where i implement the `Action Listeners` exactlythe same as for my `MainWindow`. Sadly it didn't fix the issue.
- Having `MainController` adding all the `Action Listeners` from a single `ButtonListener` class.
- Having `MainController` add all the `Action Listeners` from two different `Action Listener` classes.

At this point i ran out of ideas and i suspect that i might be missing something crucial to understand why it doesn't work. I'm pretty new when it comes to implementing MVC so i will welcome any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add actionListener to Button created by default constructor, then in actionListener:

```
optionsWindow = new OptionsWindow(mainWindow.getMainFrame());
```

You create new OptionsWindow, without connection to actionListener of SaveButton. So it is enought to add:

```
    if (ev.getSource() == mainWindow.optionsButton) {
        System.out.println("Options pressed");
        optionsWindow = new OptionsWindow(mainWindow.getMainFrame());
        optionsWindow.addOptionsButtonListener(new OptionsButtonListener()); //<-- once again add actionListener
    }
```

and it works fine with your code.

Another solution is to delete default constructor, and instead of mainFrame argument use a method:

```
public void getVisibleFrame(){
    optionsDialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

and in actionListener:

```
if (ev.getSource() == mainWindow.optionsButton) {
     optionsWindow.getVisibleFrame();
}
```

However I don't know if it is compatible with MVC.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. My main goal is to basically make that window visible and implement working `Action Listener`. I accomplished that thanks to your answer. I learned that MVC with swing is a wild ride and i'm not sure if there is a better solution than what you provided.